# SFTP Access to multiple directories for different groups

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, sftp

We have 3 groups. testuser is part of sftponly and cbpp-uat. userdev is part of cbpp-uat and cbpp-ci.

testuser is unable to connect to SFTP server when he/she is in both sftponly and cbpp-uat.
But able to connect if he is in either one of the group.

```
bala@ip-10-0-10-xx:/$ ls -ld cbpp*
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Apr 14 16:29 cbpp
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep  2 07:56 cbpp-dev
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 12288 Sep 17 02:59 cbpp-uat
bala@ip-10-0-10-xx:/$ 



Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /cbpp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand  internal-sftp -l VERBOSE  -f LOCAL7

Match Group cbpp-uat
        ChrootDirectory /cbpp-uat
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand  internal-sftp -l VERBOSE  -f LOCAL7

Match User cbpp-ci
        ChrootDirectory /cbpp-dev
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand  internal-sftp -l VERBOSE  -f LOCAL7
```

My requirement is, when testuser logs on the SFTP server, he/she should be able browse then files under both /cbpp and /cbpp-uat. How can I make it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current setup seems wrong logically, the server wouldn't know which which config to use and can't be both.

You can play with the structure of the folders

- Nest them `/cbpp/cbpp-uat` or reverse `/cbpp-uat/cbpp`
- Use bind mount, create new folder `/cbpp2` then bind mount `/cbpp` to `/cbpp2/cbpp` and `/cbpp-uat` to `/cbpp2/cbpp-uat`. Use `/cbpp2` for group that need access to both.